# how to do the github social login with nestjs?

Tags: github, nestjs, github-api

Is there any clear documentation to do the **GitHub** auth and the verifying in **Nestjs?**.
I could not find a way to implement the Github social login with nestjs.

Comment: maybe this repo could help you: https://github.com/TrejGun/session-based-rest-authorization-for-nestjs

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [Github strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-github2/) using Passport.js

`github.strategy.js`

```js
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ githubId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

`auth.controller.ts`

```js
app.get('/auth/github',
  passport.authenticate('github', { scope: [ 'user:email' ] }));

app.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

> It's an Express example, easily convertible to NestJS

Comment: It's not Nest JS approach but a standard express one.

Comment: And the problem is that it doesn't work because of CORS.